# how can i get refScrollView.current value in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native

I want to get my scroll position using a SrollView.

when I use my code and check `console.log(refScrollView.current)`

it says `null``

how can I get `refScrollView.current` value?

this is my code

```
    import React, { createRef} from 'react';

    import {ScrollView} from 'react-native';


    const Test = ({}) => {
      const refScrollView = createRef();
    
    
      console.log(refScrollView.current);
      return (
        <>
          <ScrollView ref={refScrollView}>
            ........
          
          </ScrollView>
        </>
      );
    };

    export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property onScroll is able to return what you need.

Here's how:

```
import React, { createRef} from 'react';

    import {ScrollView} from 'react-native';


    const Test = () => {

      function handleScroll(event){
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
      }

      return (
        <>
          <ScrollView onScroll{(e)=> handleScroll(e) }>
            ........
          
          </ScrollView>
        </>
      );
    };

    export default Test;
```